# Is there a way to take a screenshot of an entire HTML page including content below the fold?

Tags: screenshot

For an app demo explanation, I'd like to take a screenshot and mark it up with explanations. For that reason, I'd like the screen image to be contiguous and not cut up into multiple screenshots to explain one page.

Is there a way to take a screenshot of an entire HTML page including content below the fold?

Comment: Programmatically, or just using some software?

Comment: If you're using Firefox or Chrome, there's plugins you could use. What browser?

Answer (score 2):

there is firefox plugin [screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/) and also web page [browsershots](http://www.browsershots.org)

Comment: Thanks! Just found a good one for Chrome as well: Awesome Screenshot

Answer (score 2):

we have solved this problem with [usersnap.com](http://usersnap.com)! It's easy to install and you don't have to care about the technical details behind.